# How to authenticate Docker with VSTS?

Tags: azure, docker, tfs, azure-pipelines, build-agent

With a *self-hosted agent*, I m getting following error at the end of VSTS build pipeline.

> 2018-10-04T12:11:10.3334402Z ##[error]unauthorized: authentication required
>   2018-10-04T12:11:10.3447576Z ##[error]/snap/bin/docker failed with return code: 1

The point is I want to push Docker image to [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/), using Docker [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker).

When I perform exactly **same pipeline** on my Ubuntu machine, where agent builds, just **with Docker commands, push succeeds**. Build succeeds and repository is pushed to cloud.

How can I authenticate Docker for my build agent, to be able to push?